# Devexpress Navigation Menu makes screen to freez

Tags: c#, navigation, devexpress, validation, menuitem

I've a devexpress Navigation menu item that opens a data entry form (user control). The user control has validation rules that compel users not to leave textboxs blank. And, it works pretty good so far.

But, the problem comes when I click on other menu items while the data entry user control is already displayed. This time, the screen just freezes and stucks, and I've to restart the system. What are the possible causes and solutions? Thanks in advance
Here are some code snapshots:

```
    //Here is what I've on the main form. It has a panel control called mainPanel to display the user controls   
    private XtraUserControl uc;

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        displayUserControl("Data Entry");
        //...
    }
    private void navigationBar_LinkClicked(object sender, DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarLinkEventArgs e)
    {
        displayUserControl(e.Link.Caption);
    }

    private void displayUserControl(string link)
    {
        switch (link)
        {
            case "Data Entry":
                uc = new ucDataEntry(); //the data entry user control that freezes the system
                break;
            case "Setting":
                uc = new ucSetting();
                break;
            case "Chart":
                uc = new UCReportChart();
                break;
        }

        mainPanel.Controls.Clear();
        mainPanel.Controls.Add(uc);
        uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        uc.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging to see where it gets stuck?

Comment: The debug output says: "The thread '<No Name>' (0x10e8) has exited with code 0 (0x0)"

Comment: Can you post the code for your forms? (The form containing the navigation menu and the data entry form.)

Answer (score 0):

Any time a menu item is clicked, you are clearing the previous control out of your main panel, and replacing it with a new one. Perhaps it is the validation logic in the ucDataEntry control that is causing the application to hang? (You haven't posted code for that control, so I can't be sure.)

As an aside, by calling mainPanel.Controls.Clear(), you are leaking memory. The documentation for this function states that you must explicitly call the Dispose() method for any controls that are cleared in this manner.

Comment: But, when i put uc.Dispose() before mainPanel.Controls.Clear(), it throws an exception. How can I dispose the controls?

Comment: Sorry, I figured out how to dispose. And, here is one simple code I used to validate
        private void NameTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isNameInCorrectFormat(NameTextBox.Text).Equals(False))
            {
                 NameTextBox.SelectAll();
                 NameTextBox.Focus();
            }
        }